# PHP: How to detect if a URL starts with 'm.'?

Tags: php

I use CakePHP's built-in method `$this->RequestHandler->isMobile()` to detect mobile device, but it didn't work when I wanted to try my app using desktop browser. So I use this following code, since its url starts with 'm.' for example 'm.mywebsite.com':

```
    <?php
    $url = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    if($url[0] == 'm'){
      echo "Welcome to our mobile version";
     }
    ?>
```

But somehow it also didn't work when tested on another server that has subdomain address like 'm.trial.mywebsite2.com'. Is there any other better detection code for this kind of web address?

Comment: What is returned if you add `echo $url[0];` to your code?

Comment: In my localhost, 'm.localhost.com', returns 'm'. but in another server, 'm.trial.xxxxx.com' it returns 'trial'.

Answer (score 2):

Use Regular Expression, or simply strpos() it.

```
// Regular Expression
if (preg_match('/^m\./', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
}

// strpos()
if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'm.')) {
}
```

Your situation smells like there is something wrong in `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, you should really give it a check.

Comment: you're right, but I think it's better to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: Property HTTP_HOST rely solely on request/response headers to appear in $_SERVER, which at least requires a proper configuration on server side. Use it with care.